# Why does [NSOutlineView clickedRow] always return -1?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have a fairly pedestrian non-editable `NSOutlineView` setup. In the bindings for the outline view, I have set the Double Click Target binding to my file's owner (`MyDocument` FWIW) with a selector of `outlineViewWasDoubleClicked`

The method exists and is called, but when I call `-clickedRow` it consistently returns -1 rather than the row number of the row that I double clicked to trigger the method.

My `_outlineView` is an IBOutlet and I've verified that it is hooked up correctly by using `-selectedRow` for the method rather than `-clickedRow` (I would rather use `-clickedRow` though because it seems unintuitive for the user to have a row selected, double click another row to do something with it and have the method triggered with the row they had selected.)

My best guess right now is that the `-clickedRow` value is getting cleared out before my method fires, but I don't know where or what might be gobbling it up.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What specific “bindings” are you referring to?

Comment: The Double Click Target binding. Edited in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me. I suggest [filing it](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and, in the meantime, setting the view's target and double-click action in code.

Comment: You're right. When I `setTarget:` and `setDoubleAction:` in code, it works a treat.